# Getting nullpointerexception only when assigning the class/method to a button

Tags: apex

I am getting `NullPointerException` only when assigning the class/method to a custom button. The issue appears only when clicking the button (I'm not passing any parameters). There is a lot more code but I drilled down to the issue line as seen below. Can you please help?

```
global class res_TriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler{

    global res_TriggerHandler() { }
    webservice static void createRecord(){       
        //Issue is always on this line even after removing all other code 
        for(Resource__c reso : (List<Resource__c>)Trigger.New) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you adding the button on the same object that this class expects?

Comment: Yes Jayant that is correct.

Comment: Have you put a system.debug and see what `Trigger.New` value is? Are you sure the issue is on the line you have mentioned? If your code is running from a trigger, then that should never be `null` as long as it is running in the right trigger context.

Comment: Thanks Jayant. I got it resolved. See my response to David. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Trigger.New` is a [trigger context variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm). Trigger context variable are available to you only when you are operating within a trigger (or code called from a trigger).

In code called as a web service from a Custom Button, `Trigger.New` is not available and will result in a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Alright David I created a separate class just for the button without the trigger framework and it worked perfectly fine. I don't need to create records on edit and the button functionality at the same time. Your commend guided me in the proper direction. Thanks for helping a newbie.